# Ffmpeg concat filter produces frames from different videos

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-encoding, ffmpeg-filters

I have a workflow in which I give several videos to ffmpeg, each video corresponding to a shot, and ffmpeg concatenates them to produce a single video, interlaced at 25 fps. The problem is that sometimes, on the output video, the shot borders are made up of half a frame of each shot. For example, between shot A and shot B I have a frame made up of half an image of A and half an image of B.
Here is my command

```
ffmpeg -i clip-1.mp4 -i clip-2.mp4 -i clip-3.mp4 -filter_complex [0:v]scale=(iw*sar)*min(1920/(iw*sar)\,1080/ih):ih*min(1920/(iw*sar)\,1080/ih):sws_flags=bicubic+accurate_rnd+full_chroma_inp+full_chroma_int:sws_dither=bayer,pad=1920:1080:(1920-iw*min(1920/iw\,1080/ih))/2:(1080-ih*min(1920/iw\,1080/ih))/2,minterpolate='fps=50:mi_mode=dup',setsar=sar=1/1[v0];[0:a:0]channelsplit[a00][a01];[1:v]scale=(iw*sar)*min(1920/(iw*sar)\,1080/ih):ih*min(1920/(iw*sar)\,1080/ih):sws_flags=bicubic+accurate_rnd+full_chroma_inp+full_chroma_int:sws_dither=bayer,pad=1920:1080:(1920-iw*min(1920/iw\,1080/ih))/2:(1080-ih*min(1920/iw\,1080/ih))/2,minterpolate='fps=50:mi_mode=dup',setsar=sar=1/1[v1];[1:a:0]channelsplit[a10][a11];[2:v]scale=(iw*sar)*min(1920/(iw*sar)\,1080/ih):ih*min(1920/(iw*sar)\,1080/ih):sws_flags=bicubic+accurate_rnd+full_chroma_inp+full_chroma_int:sws_dither=bayer,pad=1920:1080:(1920-iw*min(1920/iw\,1080/ih))/2:(1080-ih*min(1920/iw\,1080/ih))/2,minterpolate='fps=50:mi_mode=dup',setsar=sar=1/1[v2];[2:a:0]channelsplit[a20][a21];[v0][a00][a01][v1][a10][a11][v2][a20][a21]concat=n=3:v=1:a=2[out][a0][a1];[out]tinterlace=interleave_top:flags=low_pass_filter,setdar=dar=16/9,setsar=sar=1/1[vout] -map [vout] -map [a0] -map [a1] -c:a pcm_s16le -ar 48k -tune psnr -field_order tt -top 1 -flags +ildct+ilme -timecode 00:00:00:00 -c:v libx264 -s hd1080 -vsync vfr -r 25 -pix_fmt yuv422p10le -aspect 16:9 -x264opts videoformat=component:nal-hrd=cbr:videoformat=component:avcintra-class=100:interlaced:tff -max_muxing_queue_size 4096 -threads 0 -y output.mxf
```

Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may be inevitable with concat. If you can use a fade filter to transition between two filters, try that instead. It may smoothen the artifacts but the FFmpeg command can get complicated if you have too many shots. You will have to write a script that constructs the filter option in a loop before use it a command with ffmpeg.

Comment: In fact, one solution would be to use ffprobe to check the number of frames in each clip, and for clips with an odd number of frames, remove one frame to obtain an even number. But this complicates my workflow, so as you suggested, I simply added a transition (black screen) between shots.